# RegEx on URL: any 3rd level domain except www

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewrite-module

I want to match/capture the 3rd level domain name for a url except www.  So capture www1.domain.com or myurl.domain.com but not www.domain.com.  How to write this?

Comment: which programming language are you using ?

Comment: Have a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one. Try with `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.domain\.com$" />`.

Answer (score -1):

Filter your list and remove any entry that matches ^www. patter.

It basically say "what ever that begins with www. (back slash just escapes the . other wise you would match www1 without the backslash)